# calling loadTheme from a .ts file

Tags: typescript, office-ui-fabric, fluent-ui, office-ui-fabric-react, fluentui-react

I one of my "office-ui-fabric-react" project, I am writing a utility class(common.ts) where I have a function to load theme for a page. This utility class will be included as part of the script tag in an html file as common.js.

I want to call loadTheme which is defined in \node_modules@uifabric\styling\lib\styles\node_modules@uifabric\styling\lib\styles\theme.d.ts

I tried **import { loadTheme } from "office-ui-fabric-react"** and gave me a generic build error.

How do I import APIs defined in "office-ui-fabric-react" from a .ts file?

Comment: "... _gave me a generic build error_" - what was the error? Can you post it?

Comment: It basically said "cannot find common". The class in which I am using loadTheme. The error was not related to loadTheme and hence did not post initially. when I comment the import, there is no error but then I can't use loadTheme.